# how to insert bytes into array with shifting?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array, for example:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

I want to insert the smaller array into:

The array which I want to insert after the third index of the original array:

```
{11,11,11}
```

So the final array should look like this:

```
{0,1,2,3,11,11,11,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

as you can see I need to keep the original values of the array, shift them left, and put the new array instead of it.
I was looking into
[Array.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0)
But it's overwriting the original values, not shifting them

Comment: You'll need a new array to accommodate the combined one, so allocate that and use three times `Array.Copy()` to copy first part of array1, then array2, then second part of array1.

Comment: Is an array the best data structure to be using here? Even if it uses an array behind the scenes, surely just being able to write `InsertRange(3, otherData)` on a `List<byte>` would let you concentrate on *getting work done* rather than fussing around with copying array values around, etc.

Comment: You don't really want an array but a List<T>.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i will need to write the result data with filestream into the file, that's why its byte array

Comment: @TaW   i will need to write the result data with filestream into the file, that's why its byte array

Comment: You can do (just about) anything you can do with an array with a List<T> as well. Its `ToList()` method will help, when necessary..

Comment: If you are using .net 5.0 or later you can write a `List<byte>` to a `FileStream` without having to convert to an array using `fileStream.Write(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(listOfBytes));` (This does not make a copy of the data so it's very efficient, but you mustn't change the `listOfBytes` in another thread while `fileStream.Write()` is doing its thing.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *Linq* to *query* `array` and assign the result back to it:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
 int[] insert = new int[] {11, 11, 11};

 array = array
   .Take(4)
   .Concat(insert)
   .Concat(array.Skip(4)) 
   .ToArray();
```

If you are looking for *low level* `Array` methods:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] insert = new int[] { 11, 11, 11 };

int at = 4;

Array.Resize<int>(ref array, array.Length + insert.Length);

Array.Copy(array, at, array, at + insert.Length, array.Length - at - insert.Length);
Array.Copy(insert, 0, array, at, insert.Length);
```

Comment: Nice minimal solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array to an list. A list is like an array, but you can easily add, insert or remove values. See this code:

```
int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int[] insert = new int[] {11, 11, 11};

List<int> list = new List<int>(array);
list.InsertRange(4, insert);
        
array = list.ToArray(); // convert the list back to an array
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GeEAeU